# Phpmyadmin(APPSERV v:2.5.9) Why can not i access to phpmyadmin main page

Tags: passwords, localhost, root, appserver

When i try to go to "localhost/phpymadmin", it asks me to enter name and password

```
name : root
password: 123
```

altough i enter my password true, i cannot reach it, it asks me over and over again.

Comment: The password is no longer `123` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

When you install AppServ it asks for user name and password, there you can set your own user name and password.

you can try user=root, and password=root

try this hopefully it will give you access

Thanks